# Почему нельзя поддержать комментарий на выборах?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, выборы

Я всё же хочу вынести это на мету. Несколько раз подымался вопрос, но все решили, что так-было-задумано и прошли мимо.

Я о выборах и о [топике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/), где можно задавать вопросы кандидатам.

Возможно, эта страница технологически отличается от обычного топика на основном сайте или на мете, но очень не хватает возможности поставить апвоут на понравившемся комментарии.

Допустим, кто-то написал комментарий с которым я полностью согласен -- и я, как избиратель, хочу подчеркнуть своё согласие с высказанным, придать дополнительный вес словам говорящего, не загромождая дублями тему или хламом "+1", "согласен" и "ППКС".

Мне кажется, что это даёт дополнительную информацию как кандидатам, так и избирателям, так и полезно в исторической ретроспективе много спустя выборов.

Предлагаю: надо поискать возможность допилить движок, чтобы была реализована такая хорошая фича.

Comment: В лучшем случае - на метамету надо, но скорее всего пошлют лесом.

Comment: @Other На MSE закроют как дубль. :)

Comment: @Squidward, Прекрасно было бы увидеть оригинал дубля.